# Mixing Formatting Conditions with C# on Excel Addin programming

Tags: c#, excel, formatting

I have a problem with Excel programmatically formatting, I tried to search for previous similar questions but this seems new

```
FormatCondition format_rows = sheet.Rows.FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression,XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual, "=MOD(ROW();2) = 0");
format_rows.Interior.Color = Color.Blue;
FormatCondition format_nums = sheet.Rows.FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue,XlFormatConditionOperator.xlLess, "=0");
format_nums.Font.Color = Color.Red;
```

With this code I get Blue BackGround Cells with the ODD rows and I should get Red numbers whenever they are negatives, but the numbers are Red only on the  EVEN rows, as shown in the picture

It seems like the Excel is giving priority to the first condition over the second

How could I get Red negative numbers on the whole sheet?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjXsG.png